# Как запретить Enter в textarea?

Tags: html, javascript

Есть textarea `<textarea onkeypress='if(event.keyCode == 13){SendMessage($myid, $id, this);}'></textarea>` клавиша Enter используется для запуска функции обработки(javascript) но в самой textarea, Enter всё ещё работает. Как его запретит так, чтобы когда пользователь  нажимал Enter запускалась только функция, а в тексте не ставился переход на новую строку, вообще чтобы в тексте ничего не происходило!
Как это реализовать ?

Answer (score 4):

Как я понял вы ищите preventDefault

```
$('input selector').on('keydown', function( e ) {
  if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    whenEnterPressed();
  }
});
```

Comment: Да ищу именно это! Но без jQuery, нужен чистый код!

Comment: preventDefault - стандартная функция. Смело юзайте её.

Comment: Стандартная функция ?! И как мне её юзать без подключения к сайту jQuery библиотек?

Comment: @Kirpich643 - все, что в этом коде делает jquery - это навешивает обработчик события. Если вы хотите навесить обработчик без использования jquery, то вам поможет гугл :)

Хотя, может быть, [этого](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) будет достаточно, удачи в реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Неужели вы сами этого не видете? Запретить нажатие для печати, но разрешить для отправки сообщения... печаль. Событий типа **onkeypressPrint()** и **onkeypressSendData()** - пока не придумали. Поэтому или же вы допускаете нажатие Enter внутри textarea, или же запрещаете использование вообще. И без вариантов.